# How do I log non-SSL connections to MySQL 5.5?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, ssl

I've recently converted my applications to connect to MySQL 5.5 using SSL. However, I'm afraid that I've missed something, so I'm also allowing non-SSL connections to the server.

How can I log incoming connections to flag any that are connecting using the old, non-SSL method?